# Shrinkwrap modifier not using subdivision surface vertices

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

The reason the shrinkwrap modifier won't work properly is apparently because I have too few vertices in the relevant part of my mesh. (See [my previous question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/85106/snap-and-shrinkwrap-wont-keep-above-surface?noredirect=1#comment149771_85106).) However, I thought that the shrinkwrap modifier was using the vertices generated by the subdivision surface modifier. This doesn't seem to be the case.

How do I make my shrinkwrap modifier use the vertices generated by the subdivision surface modifier?

Thank you.

Comment: I think I might just need to make sure the original mesh is not hidden and I'm not on wire frame view for the problem to be solved. I added in an edge loop, but it only worked when I did those two things.

Comment: Please post an image that shows the settings and order for the modifiers. Subsurf should be used before the shrinkwrap.

Comment: As cegaton said, the modifiers are a stack.  First in, first out.  The one on top should be subdivision.  After that, shrinkwrap.